# Java print result every 10th iteration of a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to write simple function to print a message every `5th` or `10th` iteration of `for loop`. for example:

In this code I want to print `i` each tenth iteration:

```
private void calc() {
    int broadcast_by_percent = 100 / 10;
    int calculate = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i == calculate) {
            calculate = broadcast_by_percent + 10;
            Log.e("i:= ", i + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every 5 or every 10?

Comment: Actually you don't have to use an if statement to do that, you just need to pass the step in the for loop, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think this one is specifically 10. My guess is the OP was saying he was making 2 differnt methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use an `if statement` while you can do it simply using a `for loop` with a specific `step`, here's the code:

```
int step = 10;
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=step) {
    Log.e("i:= ", i + "");
}
```

The instruction will only run for each `10th` index, and you can specify the step you need.

Here's a [**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/ZN8z1o).

**EDIT:**

And to make sure that you take only the multiples of your `step` (avoid zero) start your loop from this `step`:

```
int step = 10;
for (int i = step; i <= 100; i+=step) {
    Log.e("i:= ", i + "");
}
```

Notice the `i=step` here.

Comment: I know this is old, but just wanted to leave this here in case anyone stumbled upon it like I did:  This is not performing a certain operation for every 10th iteration of the loop, it is performing the operation for EVERY iteration, but only doing 1/10 of the iterations.

Comment: I think this solution resolves not the posted question! As @PAULUS mentioned, this does only 10 iteration, but the feature should be, that it should be logged out something after each 10th of an iteration. I can just imagine, that the target was, to do something 100 (or unlimited) times, but log out the status after each 10th iteration, to be able to see that the process is still running. So -1 for this solution. Actually the question is also a bit badly specified I think so I understand the confusion. And it prints out 0 and 20. Iterates over 100 times. The solution with the if % is better!

Comment: I just wanted to share something easier and that prevents from looping over all elements to do the required `Log` action for every `10th`  element. Of course if we shuld loop over all the elements we should use the original `for`loop.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the `%` operator to check that the loop variable is a multiply of 10:

```
int stepSize = 10;
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % stepSize == 0) {
        Log.e("i:= ", i + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: @mahdipishguy yes, of course. Check out my edit where I moved it to a new variable (`stepSize`). You can assign whatever value you want to it.

Comment: I like this solution a bit more.  

What could be missing (because the question itself is old and a bit not understandable) I would add one extra line into the code between the for and if like `// do some stuffs here` ...to understand, that the for iterates and does stuffs 100 times, and also logs out the i for each 10th iteration (to know, that the process, the iteration ist still running).  

At least I can imagine that, that the question was because of that needs.